# How do I know if a String is a number in scientific notation?

Tags: java, scientific-notation

I know how to check if a String is a number.  But how do you check if a String is a number and the String is in scientific notation?

Here's what I've tried: I've written an algorithm that simply checks if the string contains "E", but I'm not sure if that's enough.

I'm looking for an method implementation like this:

```
public boolean isScientificNotation(String numberString) {

    //show me the implementation

}
```

Answer (score 6):

You could use `BigDecimal`. Validation of the notation format itself is done using a simple `contains` expression

```
static boolean isScientificNotation(String numberString) {

    // Validate number
    try {
        new BigDecimal(numberString);
    } catch (NumberFormatException e) {
        return false;
    }

    // Check for scientific notation
    return numberString.toUpperCase().contains("E");   
}
```

Comment: for Strng like 1113E, or 1343e3, actually any string only have an "e" or "E" inside. cannot identify correclty.  It should be a normal string, but will return as  ScientificNotation.

Answer (score 2):

```
private  boolean isScientificNotation(String numberString) {

    // Validate number
    try {
        new BigDecimal(numberString);
    } catch (NumberFormatException e) {
        return false;
    }

    // Check for scientific notation
    return numberString.toUpperCase().contains("E") && (numberString.charAt(1)=='.' || numberString.charAt(2)=='.');   
}
```

Revised a little. If the string is a normalized scientific notation, it should have a dot/"." in the second place, and also have E/e somewhere.

Comment: what if negative number?

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
if(containsE(str))   //call your method to check if "e" is present
{
    try
    {
        Double.parseDouble(str);
        return true;
    }
    catch(NumberFormatException e)
    {
        return false;
    }
}
else
    return false;
```

Comment: Just to be sure, what's the impl of `containsE`?  Are you doing `str.contains("E");`?  I'm a little concerned because in a comment you wrote to check for "e".  My tests always show that the uppercase E is valid.

Comment: @tieTYT When I said `containsE(str)`, I was referring to the algorithm that you said you  wrote in your question.

Comment: @tieTYT You could do a `toUpperCase()` on the string and then check for `E`.

Comment: The beginning of your code fragment could just be `if (!containsE(str)) return false;`

Comment: my question is asking for the impl of `containsE`.  I know it's trivial, but if you show me that impl and it's correct, I'll mark yours as the answer.

Comment: @tieTYT Oh...You said that you had *written* the algorithm in your own question.

Comment: yes, but I said "but I'm not sure if that's enough".  That's the point of my question :)